# How to achieve this style in visual C++?

Tags: visual-c++

Is this kind of style available in VC++ or need third-party resources? If it's native, how to set the style to this in VC++?

[image]

Comment: What GUI framework, if any, are you using? Also, you'll need a time machine that can return you to 2001.

Comment: Which version of (I assume Visual Studio) are you using?

Comment: @LukasHäfliger I am using Visual C++ 2012

Comment: I think that's the Office 2002 theme. Pretty sure you can still select it in the MFC Application Wizard, when creating a new MFC project.

Comment: This is MFC with Feature Pack (first available with VS2008 SP1)

Comment: Just checked, it only goes back to Office 2003 theme.

Comment: @ta.speot.is Can I use this without MFC, just use plan win32 api?

Comment: Set the time machine back one decade and hit up CodeProject. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22/Cool-Owner-Drawn-Menus-with-Bitmaps-Version-3-03  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2354/Owner-Drawn-Menu-with-Icons-Titles-and-Shading http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8715/Owner-drawn-menus-in-two-lines-of-code They're called owner-drawn menus. The code is for MFC, but you can remove the MFC bits if you're patient enough and rewrite it as native Win32.

Answer (score 1):

In the resource file *.rc of your project you need to do add these changes-

> POPUP "Language", IDD_NameofID
>
> ```
>   BEGIN
>      MENUITEM "Chinese CB",  IDD_somename1
>      MENUITEM "English",     IDD_somename2
>   END
> ```